# Como puedo limitar a 11 caracteres la variable cedula en C++?

Tags: c++

Necesito ayuda, como puedo limitar a 11 caracteres la variables cedula?
Código

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct trabajador
{
    string nombre;
    int edad;
    int cedula;
};

trabajador empleado[20];
int canttrab=0;

//Función cara Adicionar una estructura trabajador
void AdicionarTrabajador()
{
    cout<<"Entre la cantidad de trabajadores que desea gestionar: ";
    cin>>canttrab;
    for (int i=1; i<=canttrab; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Entre el nombre: ";
        cin>>empleado[i].nombre;
        {
            cout<<"entre la edad:"; cin>>empleado[i].edad;
            if (empleado[i].edad>=18){
                cout<<"";
            }
            else if(empleado[i].edad<18){
                cout<<"\nusted es menor de edad no puede trabajar";
                exit(1);
            }
            cout<<"Entre la cedula: ";
            cin>>empleado[i].cedula;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código como texto no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que se hace tedioso o imposible replicar tu problema.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: ¿Qué significa "limitar a 11 caracteres"? ¿Te refieres a 11 dígitos? ¿Qué debe hacer en caso negativo? ¿Rechazar y volver a pedir datos? ¿Todos? ¿No guardar datos? ¿Guardar un valor por defecto?